# How to manage static files in django project with many apps?

Tags: django

I am developing a web app based on django for a while. At the beginning, I just put all the static files such as css, js and some icons in one folder and served the folder as static files. While the project evolves, more and more apps added, and there are too many files stored in the folder.

Therefore, I would like to reorganize static files. What would be a good way? Should I classify files according to the apps they belong to or classify them by css, img, and js, or classify by apps first, and then by their types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably do a mix. Project wide templates and static files could be stored in one central location. And all the app related files would be stored in a dedicated static-subdirectory in each app's folder.

If you use Django 1.3 [`contrib.staticfiles`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#managing-static-files) makes this really easy.
It even provides a handy [`collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic) command, that fetches the static files from all your apps and stores them in a central, configurable location, where you can serve them from.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar project and organized by app first and then by type, just like you would do with templates. To me it seems more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I go from general to specific for organization,which would suggest an organization from apps to file types. I would also recommend taking any files that are shared across apps and moving them into a shared hierarchy.